# open pdf in android using foxit reader SDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, foxit, foxit-reader

in my app i have to open pdf. and i am using FOXIT READER SDK..  and i have successfully configure android NDK to use C/C++ code. i am try to run its demo.

here is my log cat error.

Memory manager created
sn = XXXXDTEMP,code = XXXXXXA96AB2BF3C4021EC71EB189CD77E68DFB2
10-03 
FPDFEMB TRACE: FS_LoadJbig2Decoder called

FPDFEMB BENCHMARK: FS_LoadJbig2Decoder, 0 ticks

FPDFEMB TRACE: Loading JPEG2000 decoder called

FPDFEMB BENCHMARK: Loading JPEG2000 decoder, 0 ticks

FPDFEMB TRACE: FS_FontCMap_LoadGB called

FPDFEMB BENCHMARK: FS_FontCMap_LoadGB, 0 ticks

FPDFEMB TRACE: FS_FontCMap_LoadGBExt called

FPDFEMB BENCHMARK: FS_FontCMap_LoadGBExt, 0 ticks

FPDFEMB TRACE: FS_FontCMap_LoadCNS called

FPDFEMB BENCHMARK: FS_FontCMap_LoadCNS, 0 ticks

FPDFEMB TRACE: FS_FontCMap_LoadKorea called

FPDFEMB BENCHMARK: FS_FontCMap_LoadKorea, 0 ticks

FPDFEMB TRACE: FS_FontCMap_LoadJapan called

FPDFEMB BENCHMARK: FS_FontCMap_LoadJapan, 0 ticks

FPDFEMB TRACE: FS_FontCMap_LoadJapanExt called

FPDFEMB BENCHMARK: FS_FontCMap_LoadJapanExt, 0 ticks

FPDFEMB TRACE: FPDFEMB_SetFontMapper called

FPDFEMB BENCHMARK: FPDFEMB_SetFontMapper, 0 ticks

FPDFEMB TRACE: FS_Memory_Alloc called

FPDFEMB BENCHMARK: FS_Memory_Alloc, 0 ticks

**DocLoad = FPDFDocLoad: Doc did not load properly**

here i think pdf document not load properly...

can i use another alternative to open pdf.. but pdf want to open only in my app.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I got the same issue. (I've copy correct pdf to /mnt/sdcard in device or emulator already.) But doesn't work. The app crash. I get the same error "Doc did not load properly")

Comment: still not solved..help me if it will solve.

Comment: My problem is I forgot to use the real API key.But I thnk mupdf is better solution. I'm quite happy with it now.